# How to change button color if button active or selected using Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, button, colors

I want to change button color if the button is active or selected.

This is my code:

**template**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary mb-3"
        @click="btnBlue()"
      >
        Blue
      </button>
      <button
        class="btn btn-warning text-white mx-3 mb-3"
        @click="btnYellow()"
      >
       Yellow
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span
        class="btn-map"
        v-for="(item, index) in new Array(data.length)"
        :key="index"
      >
        <button
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
          :class="{ active: index + 1 === activeButton }"
          :style="{ 'background-color': color}"
          @click="setActive(index)"
        >
          {{ index + 1 }}
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Script**

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data() {
    return {
      data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      color: "",
      activeButton: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setActive(index) {
      this.activeButton = index + 1;
    },
    btnBlue() {
      this.color = '#039BE5';
    },
    btnYellow() {
      this.color = '#f3b808';
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

This is the : [demo link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-1lbdsr?file=src%2FApp.vue)

I want to change the button color if I click the `blue` button, I want only the selected active button color is changing to `blue` not all button. If I click the `yellow` button I want only the selected active button color is changing to `yellow` not all button dan if no button selected then button `blue` or `yellow` clicked, I want no color changed. So the color only change on selected or active button and color not changing if no button selected or active.

Please help me to change the color button only on selected active button.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you mean something like that?

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      data: [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      color: "",
      activeButton: 0
    }
  },
  methods: {
    setActive(index) {
      this.activeButton = index + 1;
    },
    btnBlue() {
      this.color = '#039BE5';
    },
    btnYellow() {
      this.color = '#f3b808';
    }
  }
}).mount('#demo')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="demo">
    <div>
      <button
        class="btn btn-primary mb-3"
        @click="btnBlue()"
      >
        Blue
      </button>
      <button
        class="btn btn-warning text-white mx-3 mb-3"
        @click="btnYellow()"
      >
       Yellow
      </button>
    </div>
    <div>
      <span
        class="btn-map"
        v-for="(item, index) in new Array(data.length)"
        :key="index"
      >
        <button
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
          :style="{'background-color': activeButton === index + 1 ? color : ''}"
          @click="setActive(index)"
        >
          {{ index + 1 }}
        </button>
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I just added a condition into your `v-for`:

```
:style="{'background-color': activeButton === index + 1 ? color : ''}"
```

so if the button with the index+1 matches the activeButton the variable `color` will be used, else no color will be applied.